# How do i display new partial after last instead of before?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have this code, which creates a new "incident" partial and displays it BEFORE the last one. Is there a way to tell it to display it AFTER instead?

```
@{
    foreach (var incident in Model.allIncidents.ToList())
    {
        Model.newIncident = incident;
        @Html.Partial("IncidentBodyPartial", Model)
    }
}
```

Comment: you could just reverse the list

Comment: Try `foreach (var incident in Model.allIncidents.Reverse().ToList())`

Comment: The Reverse is giving me an error.